# Refactoring Code to reflect inheritance heirarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I am trying to refactor code and am having difficulty knowing where to start as I am very new to programming.

I have tried putting the methods comment, like and unlike under the class CommentedPost but do not know what to do anymore.

Post.java

```
public class Post {
private String username;  // username of the post's author
private long timestamp;
private int likes;
private ArrayList<String> comments;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Post.
 * 
 * @param author    The username of the author of this post.
 */
public Post(String author)
{
    username = author;
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    likes = 0;
    comments = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**
 * Record one more 'Like' indication from a user.
 */
public void like()
{
    likes++;
}

/**
 * Record that a user has withdrawn his/her 'Like' vote.
 */
public void unlike()
{
    if (likes > 0) {
        likes--;
    }
}

/**
 * Add a comment to this post.
 * 
 * @param text  The new comment to add.
 */
public void addComment(String text)
{
    comments.add(text);
}

/**
 * Return the time of creation of this post.
 * 
 * @return The post's creation time, as a system time value.
 */
public long getTimeStamp()
{
    return timestamp;
}

/**
 * Display the details of this post.
 * 
 * (Currently: Print to the text terminal. This is simulating display 
 * in a web browser for now.)
 */
public void display()
{
    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.print(timeString(timestamp));

    if(likes > 0) {
        System.out.println("  -  " + likes + " people like this.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println();
    }

    if(comments.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("   No comments.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("   " + comments.size() + " comment(s). Click here to view.");
    }
}

/**
 * Create a string describing a time point in the past in terms 
 * relative to current time, such as "30 seconds ago" or "7 minutes ago".
 * Currently, only seconds and minutes are used for the string.
 * 
 * @param time  The time value to convert (in system milliseconds)
 * @return      A relative time string for the given time
 */

private String timeString(long time)
{
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long pastMillis = current - time;      // time passed in milliseconds
    long seconds = pastMillis/1000;
    long minutes = seconds/60;
    if(minutes > 0) {
        return minutes + " minutes ago";
    }
    else {
        return seconds + " seconds ago";
    }
}
}
```

CommentedPost.java

```
public class CommentedPost extends Post {

public CommentedPost(String author) {
    super(author);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

EventPost.java

```
public class EventPost extends Post{

public EventPost(String author) {
    super(author);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

MessagePost.java

```
public class MessagePost extends Post{
private String message;  // an arbitrarily long, multi-line message

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class MessagePost.
 * 
 * @param author    The username of the author of this post.
 * @param text      The text of this post.
 */
public MessagePost(String author, String text)
{
    super(author);
    message = text;
}

/**
 * Return the text of this post.
 * 
 * @return The post's message text.
 */
public String getText()
{
    return message;
}

/**
 * Display the details of this post.
 * 
 * (Currently: Print to the text terminal. This is simulating display 
 * in a web browser for now.)
 */
public void display()
{
    super.display();
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

StartNetwork.java

```
public class StartNetwork{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    MessagePost message = new MessagePost("White Rabbit", "Oh dear, oh dear, I shall be late!");
    PhotoPost photo = new PhotoPost("Alice Wonderland", "RabbitHole.jpg" ,"Down the rabbit hole :)");

    message.addComment( "Your watch is exactly two days slow." );
    photo.like();

    NewsFeed news = new NewsFeed();

    news.addPost( message );
    news.addPost( photo );
    news.show();
}   
}
```

PhotoPost.java

```
public class PhotoPost extends Post{
private String filename;  // the name of the image file
private String caption;   // a one line image caption

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class PhotoPost.
 * 
 * @param author    The username of the author of this post.
 * @param filename  The filename of the image in this post.
 * @param caption   A caption for the image.
 */
public PhotoPost(String author, String filename, String caption)
{
    super(author);
    this.filename = filename;
    this.caption = caption;
}

/**
 * Return the file name of the image in this post.
 * 
 * @return The post's image file name.
 */
public String getImageFile()
{
    return filename;
}

/**
 * Return the caption of the image of this post.
 * 
 * @return The image's caption.
 */
public String getCaption()
{
    return caption;
}

/**
 * Display the details of this post.
 * 
 * (Currently: Print to the text terminal. This is simulating display 
 * in a web browser for now.)
 */
public void display()
{
    super.display();
    System.out.println("  [" + filename + "]");
    System.out.println("  " + caption);
}
}
```

NewsFeed.java

```
public class NewsFeed{
private ArrayList<Post> posts;

/**
 * Construct an empty news feed.
 */
public NewsFeed()
{
    posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
}

/**
 * Add a post to the news feed.
 * 
 * @param post  The post to be added.
 */
public void addPost(Post post)
{
    posts.add(post);
}

/**
 * Show the news feed. Currently: print the news feed details
 * to the terminal. (To do: replace this later with display
 * in web browser.)
 */
public void show()
{
    // display all posts
    for(Post post : posts) {
        post.display();
        System.out.println();   // empty line between posts
    }
}
}
```

The refactored code is supposed to have a class diagram with the following:

Post w/ fields username and timestamp

CommentedPost(arrow pointing to Post ie inheriting from it) w/ fields likes and comments

EventPost(arrow pointing to Post) w/ fields eventType

Message Post (arrow pointing to CommentedPost) w/ field message

PhotoPost (arrow pointing to CommentedPost) w/ fields filename and caption

Comment: You seem to have added the code for the StartNetwork class instead of the Post class.

Comment: You say in your text that MessagePost inherits from CommentedPost, but in your code it does not.

Comment: I have not made the changes to the code as I am unsure how to proceed. The text is saying what I have to do but I am facing difficulty

Comment: @PimvanLeeuwen I have edited to include the correct code, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post contains likes and comments. You should move these fields to CommentedPost.

I'm not sure what the field eventType is, but EventPost does not have such field. You should create it.

According to your description, MessagePost should extend CommentedPost. It does not; rather, it extends Post. You should change this such that it extends CommentedPost.

According to your description, PhotoPost should extend CommentedPost. It does not; rather, it extends Post. You should change this such that it extends CommentedPost.

Comment: I've done accordingly, but after moving the fields likes and comments to CommentedPost, there are now errors in the display method in Post. Do I move the fileds back and change them to protected instead of private or?

Comment: That is because the display method still assumes the Post class has those fields. When you refactor code like this (moving stuff into subclasses) you'll also want to move functionality into subclasses. In this case, display the fields in a (new) display method of CommentedPost rather than Post.

Comment: Sorry but does that mean I copy the display method into Commented Post and get rid of it in Post? Because I think after doing that I'll have to change the fields username and timestamp to protected in Post?

Comment: You should indeed copy it to CommentedPost and make those fields protected. However, you should not remove the method from Post; this is poor practice. This, because you want other objects to know that all Post objects (including CommentedPost objects) have this method and that other objects can reliably call the method when the Post type is not known.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand why now. Unfortunately the display method in Post still has the same errors stating that likes and comments cannot be resolved to a variable (I guess this is since they have been move to CommentedPost?)

Comment: That's the reason why. You can just get rid of those lines with errors.

Comment: Everything is running just fine now, thank you so much for your help!